# Role base menu with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there any plugins or gems for role base menu ?

How to create dynamic menu on the basis of role ?

Comment: Please rephrase the question and check the spelling. Give some examples. I have to admit that I do not understand what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at railscast :) the last video is on a template topic u can implement it as a you need :)

Comment: can you please provide a link/